# How To Calculate the DPI of Buffered Image using Java

Tags: java, image-processing

Firstly, I have to convert the image into Base64 and then calculate the DPI of an image by converting base64 to buffered Image.

Here is some code that I tried and that works well for image.PNG(.png) format but  return -1(wrong output) in other formats like(.jpg)...!
But I need this to also work for other formats too.

```
 private static float base64toBuffer(String inputbuffer) throws IOException, ImageReadException{
         byte[] Rimage=decodeToImage(inputbuffer);
       final org.apache.sanselan.ImageInfo imageInfo = Sanselan.getImageInfo(Rimage);
       final int physicalWidthDpi = imageInfo.getPhysicalWidthDpi();
       final int physicalHeightDpi = imageInfo.getPhysicalHeightDpi();
        return physicalWidthDpi;

    }
     private static byte[] buffertoByte(String imageString) {

        byte[] imageByte;
        try {
            BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
            imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
            return imageByte;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure that a BufferedImage conveys any resolution information.

Comment: Hi, you have described what seems to be a task you have been assigned, but not what your problem is in implementing this task (ie. is it converting to Base64, converting from Base64 or calculating the DPI, or all of the above?). That said, a `BufferedImage` is "just pixels". So if you want to compute a DPI for a given image, you also need input for the physical size you want that image represented.